# How can set value to input box of html and display after clicking a button using Vanilla javascript?

Tags: javascript

- Set `user id` to input box
- As a user when I click `get user posts button` that `userid` should be retrieved from input text box in order to be  displayed in `browsers's console.log()`

**Actual Resulst**
on browser console.log() id is printed before i click the button

*** Codes***

```
//click handler to get clicked user id
    const getUserPosts = (id) =>{
         console.log(id)
    }
//getData('users') has a list of ten users
getData('users').then(data=>data.forEach(({name, email, id})=>{

      var div = newTag('div')
      document.getElementsByClassName('user')[0].appendChild(div);

        let listName = newTag('h2')
        let listEmail = newTag('p')
        let userPostBtn = newTag('button')
        let input = newTag('input')
        // userPostBtn.setAttribute('onclick', e=>getUserPosts())
        userPostBtn.innerHTML = 'Get User’s Posts'      
        input.setAttribute('name', 'data')
       

        div.appendChild(listName)
        div.appendChild(listEmail)
        div.appendChild(userPostBtn)
        div.appendChild(input)
        listEmail.innerHTML = email
        listName.innerHTML=name
        input.value = id
       
    }))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this and let me know

```js
const getUserPosts = (id) =>{
     console.log(id)
}
 
    
function newTag(tagName) {
     return document.createElement(tagName);
}

function getData() {
  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users', {method: 'get'}).
  then(data => data.json()).
  then(data => {
      console.log(data)
       data.forEach(({name, email, id})=>{
      var div = newTag('div')
        document.getElementsByClassName('user')[0].appendChild(div);

        let listName = newTag('h2')
        let listEmail = newTag('p')
        let userPostBtn = newTag('button')
        let input = newTag('input')
        userPostBtn.innerHTML = 'Get User’s Posts'   
        userPostBtn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
          getUserPosts(id)
        })
        input.setAttribute('name', 'data')
        div.appendChild(listName)
        div.appendChild(listEmail)
        div.appendChild(userPostBtn)
        div.appendChild(input)
        listEmail.innerHTML = email
        listName.innerHTML=name
        input.value = id
       
    })}).catch(e => {
    console.log(e)
  })
}

getData()
```

```html
  <div class="user"></div>
```

Comment: Was about to post this solution... :D In fact you don't even need to do a custom function and then run the `getUserPosts`:) You can just pass `getUserPosts` as a callback and pass it the event as an argument ... that is unless you want to implement multiple logic there

Comment: Hmm, Yes it can work i thought OP  may add some logic or data. lets wait for the response

Comment: By using @NikolayKremenliev codes it displays `HTML` and `data` as well however click event is not working

Comment: @janvier Are you sure you are passing and handling the `Event` properly? You could see examples at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/api/eventlistener

Answer (score 0):

If you give your input an id at the time of creation (id could be anything as long as its unique): `input.id = 'inputfieldid';` then you can get the value from the input in the event listener

```js
    const getUserPosts = (id) =>{
         const input = document.getElementById('inputfieldid');
         console.log(input.value);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try changing `onclick` event to be like this:

```
userPostBtn.onclick = (e)=>getUserPosts();
```